# Проблемы в использовании android-inapp-billing-v3

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Вот так вызываю покупку:

```
unlock_full_version.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(MainActivity.this, KEY, MainActivity.this);
            bp.initialize();
            boolean isSubscriptionUpdateSupported = bp.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported();
            if(isSubscriptionUpdateSupported) {
                bp.subscribe(MainActivity.this, "item");

            }else {
                Log.e("Doesn't support", "Error");
            }
        }
    });
```

Но на isSubscriptionUpdateSupported выдаёт NullPointerException. Что не так я делаю?

**UPD**

> Process: me.pokerhelper, PID: 28178
>                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int
>   com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.isBillingSupported(int,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                   at com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported(BillingProcessor.java:355)
>                                                                   at me.pokerhelper.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:90)
>                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

**UPD**

Сделал вот так:

```
bp = new BillingProcessor (MainActivity.this, KEY, MainActivity.this);
    unlock_full_version.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buy();
        }
    });

...


public void buy(){
   bp.subscribe(MainActivity.this, "android.test.purchase");
}
```

Но теперь покупка совершается при первом запуске приложения без нажатия на кнопку :D

Comment: Стектрейс ошибки добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @eugeneek добавил, правда немного кривовато

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, KEY, this);
    unlock_full_version.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            bp.initialize();
            buy();
        }
    });
```

Вот такой код сработал.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека в коробке не успела создать экземпляр класса для работы с Сервисом, мб и сам сервис ещё не запустился.
В этой либе есть специальный callback, 

`@Override
  public void onBillingInitialized() {
    /*
    * Called when BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to purchase 
    */
  }`

который сигнализирует что Handler для работы готов попробуйте, перенести туда. 
А в целом инициализация такой тяжелой операции необходима предварительна в OnCreate например, а дальше менеджить все операции через Контроллеры.

Убедитесь также что ваш AIDL интерфейс настроен, в гугл семплс есть вполне рабочие варианты.

Comment: А не подскажите как правильно это сделать?

Comment: А то когда  `bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(MainActivity.this, KEY, MainActivity.this);
            bp.initialize();` в oncreate, это всёравно не помогает

Comment: у вас папка aidl есть в проекте, интерфейс добавлен? CallBack отловите который в ответе, прологируйте посмотрите ошибку

Comment: У меня такой папочки нет даже  0_о
Нашёл, но она пустая